# Как и где прописать путь к папке tmp, где расположена папка tmp на хостинге

Tags: файлы, изображения, php, загрузка

Здравствуйте! Я уже спрашивала насчет папки tmp и поняла, что, вроде бы, она должна присутствовать и в корне сайта, и вне его, я права? Но пока суппорт на хостинге молчит, хотелось бы узнать, может, можно как-то содать папку tmp на сайте и прописать к ней путь? Пробовала просто создавать - ничего не получилось. Какова структура папок на хостинге у вас? И еще: мне на серче посоветовали прописать один из двух кодов `chmod(ini_get('tmp_upload_dir'), 777)` или `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/custom_tmp_dir');`, но я не знаю, где расположить код, в обработчике? Папку tmp тогда нужно создавать?

Comment: Пара наводящих вопросов:  
1. Создайте файл test.php:  

    <?
    phpinfo();
    ?>

И найдите там строчку upload_tmp_dir- есть ли она там и чему равна?    
2. Вы можете редактировать php.ini ? Хостер дает Вам такую возможность?

Comment: ReinRaus, сделала как вы сказали, временная папка есть! Вот путь: /home/sh11116201/data/mod-tmp. Находится вне www. Посмотрела атрибуты, написано имя tmp, ссылается на mod-tmp. Это даже не папка а файл со стрелочкой. Напротив пути почему-то написано: no value. Что сделать, чтобы изображения загружались? На тестовом у меня просто папка tmp. Редактировать файл  php.ini  не могу, т.к. вообще не нашла его.

Comment: Поправлюсь, это ссылка ссылается на mod-tmp.

Comment: У меня на тестовом напротив пути написано tmp, на хостинге no value. Может в этом причина?

Comment: Все работает). ReinRaus, отдельное спасибо за функцию phpinfo();, посмотрела путь. В пути указана папка /mod-tmp. Ее то как раз и небыло. Создала ее за пределами www и все заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расположите эту папку там же где и находится ваш php файл, а потом вызывайте ее 'tmp/имя_файла', так будет проще.

Comment: Как вызывать, где расположить эту строчку? Я пока не очень сильна в php.