# PHPExcel не работает на дедике

Tags: php, xml, phpexcel

Пытаюсь импортировать из *xlsx* файла в *mysql* средствами *php*. На домашнем компе под управлением *OpenServer* все работает как часы, на хостинге выдает:

> Warning: include_once(/var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/phpexel.php): failed to open stream: Нет такого файла или каталога in /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/inc/import.php on line 39 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/phpexel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/inc/import.php on line 39 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open 1.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(268): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('1.xlsx') #1 /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('1.xlsx') #2 /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/inc/import.php(41): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('1.xlsx') #3 /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/inc/import.php(64): getXLS('1.xlsx') #4 /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/cpanel.php(100): include_once('/var/www/scs/da...') #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 82

сам код:

```
function getXLS($xls)
{
    include_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/phpexel.php';
    include_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xls);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $aSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    //этот массив будет содержать массивы содержащие в себе значения ячеек каждой строки
    $array = array();
    //получим итератор строки и пройдемся по нему циклом
    foreach ($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        //получим итератор ячеек текущей строки
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        //пройдемся циклом по ячейкам строки
        //этот массив будет содержать значения каждой отдельной строки
        $item = array();
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            //заносим значения ячеек одной строки в отдельный массив
            array_push($item, iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $cell->getCalculatedValue()));
        }
        //заносим массив со значениями ячеек отдельной строки в "общий массв строк"
        array_push($array, $item);
    }
    return $array;
}

$xlsData = getXLS($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); //извлеаем данные из XLS
```

Уже незнаю прям в чем дело
Версия *php* и на компе и на сервере : *5.4.44-0*

Comment: Он же явно говорит что /var/www/scs/data/www/domain.ru/engine/classes/phpexel.php не найден. Посмотрите где у вас на самом деле лежит этот файл и поправьте пути, может у вас ENGINE_DIR неправильная

Comment: в этом же файле подключается parse.class.php
include_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/parse.class.php';
И работаетнормально.

Comment: Ну вы явно на диске посмотрите. Если он говорит что файла нет - значит его там нет. Ну либо какая то экзотика с правами на него

Comment: он есть на диске, и права у него такие-же как и у parse.class.php

Comment: В поправленном вопросе стала проще читаться ошибка. php походу на месте, но они не могут найти: Could not open 1.xlsx for reading! File does not exist. Проверьте где у вас лежит этот 1.xlsx, является ли текущая директория во время выполнения скрипта той же, где лежит данный файл и есть ли на него права

Comment: Вопрос меняется, решил посмотреть `print_r($_FILES);`
Оказалось что `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` несуществует.
Весь массив `Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1.xlsx
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 6
            [size] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: из информации по ошибкам file-upload: "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
Значение: 6; Отсутствует временная папка."; Что бы это ни значило. Я не в курсе про временные папки в php, но видимо ее надо как то задавать и хостер этого не сделал или закрыл ее

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167711/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-tmp-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-tmp-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5

Comment: Если вопрос меняется, то стоило дополнить текст вопроса, а не оставлять комментарий. По сути вопроса - узнавайте у хостера почему нет временной папки для аплоада

Answer (score 1):

При установке `php` на сервере произошла ошибка. Помогла переустановка. Всем спасибо.